# I/O operation on closed file; trying to print on-screen after writing to a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to write the contents of the screen to a text file if the user selects that option.  However, Python seems to want to print `"Report Complete."` to the report.txt file, which I told it to close.  I want the "report complete" to display on the screen after it writes to the text file, and move on to the hashing function.

```
import wmi
import sys
import hashlib

c = wmi.WMI()
USB = "Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice"

print ("USB Controller Devices:")
for item in c.query(USB):
    print (item.Dependent.Caption)

print (" ")
print ("======================================")
report = input ("Would you like the results exported to a file? ")

if (report) == "yes":
    file = open('report.txt', 'w')
    sys.stdout = file
    for item in c.query(USB):
        print (item.Dependent.Caption)
    file.close()
    print ("Report complete.")

else:
    print ("Job Complete.")

hashInput = input ("Would you like to hash the report? ")
if (hashInput) == "yes":
    hash = hashlib.md5(open('report.txt', 'rb').read()).hexdigest()
    print ("The MD5 hash value is:", (hash))

else:
    print ("Job Complete.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You set `sys.stdout` to a file, and then closed the file. That makes everything you try and print, which would normally go to stdout, try and go to a closed file. If I may suggest, don't reassign `sys.stdout`. It is not necessary.

```
if report == "yes":
    with open('report.txt', 'w') as fout:
        for item in c.query(USB):
            print(item.Dependent.Caption, file=fout)
    print("Report complete.")
```

Comment: thanks, that worked perfectly.  I understood the concept but couldn't figure out how to get around it.  Much appreciated!